# Is there a way to save the YouTube MIX playlist in my playlists?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

YouTube has a new feature now, "MIX", which generates an automatic playlist of 50 videos depending on what you last saw. I used it to create a music playlist and worked while listening to it. Now I finished and I went home.

Is there a way to save the playlist (other than not closing the browser/computer) so that I can continue listening to the playlist, or listen to all of it from the start at another time and machine?

Comment: I have an answer, but I don't have the privilege to post it yet, so I'm posting it here on the comment. I created a collection of scripts that semi-automates the process of scraping "my mix" and other playlists. https://github.com/martian17/scrape_yt_playlist The scraping part is until step 6, and by then you will have a text file containing all the URLs.  
Step 7 until 13 contains the instructions on how to import these URLs to YouTube through a service called soundiiz.com.

Answer (score 6):

## New Feature

Now you can directly save a youtube Mix as a playlist using the new button beside the Mix title:

[image: Save youtube Mix to playlist]

## Old solution - not working anymore

I was also searching for an answer to this question, but I couldn't figure out how to save it to my playlists and ended up just copying the link and storing it as a comment to my own YouTube Profile. The important part of the link is the code after `&list=`.

For example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkCyhhyWekc&list=RD02VkCyhhyWekc

I hope this can still help you.

EDIT: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore. At least for my old link. But see the new feature above.

Comment: while that 'list' component is clearly the identifier for that mix list, there still doesn't seem to be any way to convert from this to the default playlist view. Simply appending it to the standard playlist URL format: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=... format does not work here, and will only result in an 'oops, something went wrong' page.

Comment: I have noticed the new feature is only available on the "My mix - {some song}" playlists. For the "My mix" playlist the save option is not available.

Comment: I created a script that semi-automatically scrapes any playlist including generic "My mix".  
https://github.com/martian17/scrape_yt_playlist  
You can import the resulting urls to YouTube through services like https://soundiiz.com/  
Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this using a web app, use http://ctrlq.org/youtube/playlists/ to copy the list url into the box and it will add it to your YouTube playlists, it's the only way i have found so far of achieving this.

Comment: hmm, are you sure you're doing this with a youtube mix list? when I tried it with this list: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atM3ZhF8MVs&list=RDatM3ZhF8MVs it only gave me 401 error

Comment: this is the correct answer. make sure your playlist privacy to be public. So that youtube-dl can download the same. Once download the videos delete the playlist.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest for me way to achieve this is to go to your history, click at the right bottom of every song you heard from this playlist and add it to the watch later category. Then you go to the Watch later and you save the playlist as yours. You will even have the same order of the songs. The only problem with that is you will have only the songs that you have already heard and not the rest of the playlist that you haven't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as the list is not of the type "My Mix"

For a "normal" mix playlist, you will be able to click the "add to Playlists" button in the upper right corner of the playlist-list (the view over the upcoming songs).
If the lists name start with "My Mix" there's no way to do this, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out a way. In the name of the mix for instance Mix - Soul Asylum - Runaway Train - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRtvqT_wMeY&list=RDNRtvqT_wMeY there is a Thumbs Up icon. If you give a like, then YouTube stores in your preferences... To replay the mix, you have to go in the left corner, there is an icon with 4 horizontal lines, you click it, and then you can find a Playlists menu. There you have the mix you liked.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your browser's favourites while it is playing one of the videos in the list. Works like what Alex described because it has `&list=` in it.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the "My Subscriptions" tab and click "Music" mine always shows up there.

Comment: This should be a comment.